# Unix socket readable only?

Tags: docker, containers

I got `rtorrent` running in a Docker container (with image `crazymax/rtorrent-rutorrent`), and I have the unix socket accessible on the host machine (`-v /rutorrent2/run:/var/run/rtorrent`).

I have another container with `flood` (`jesec/flood`), which has the unix socket from rtorrent mounted in the container (`-v /rutorrent2/run:/rtorrent/run`). After setting up the `flood` container, the `flood` instance can see the downloads from `rtorrent`, but unable to add any torrents to it.

Users running both processs are with `uid=1000`, and the permission of the socket file is `777` after `chmod`. What is the reason that `flood` can see torrents from `rtorrent` via the unix socket, but cannot add torrents? It just give error code `500` in `docker logs`.

Comment: The unix socket is `/var/run/rtorrent/sgci.socket` in the `rtorrent` container

Comment: You need to mount it `rw` with `-v /rutorrent2/run:/rtorrent/run:rw`